# How do I associate custom metadata with an index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

So, we have a MySQL store which is our persistence layer for our data. For a few search use cases, what we want to do is create Elasticsearch indices on demand by querying data from the MySQL store. We've also configured an [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) policy which deletes these indices, say, after a week from creation. In effect, these indices are ephemeral and created on demand whenever there's a search request coming in and then deleted later.

Because there's only a fixed set of data I would need to ingest into the Elasticsearch index, I want to define a state of this index which indicates the completeness of the ingestion process. This is necessary because the user isn't really allowed to perform searches until unless all the data is there - until the index is completely loaded with all the required data.

So, what I'm looking for is to associate this state as some sort of metadata of the index. Because our ILM policy dictates that these indices are ephemeral, I do not want to use an external system to manage their state. Typically, I would have to navigate across the pending, building and completed/failed states as I create the index and start the ingestion.

It seems like the [_meta](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html) mapping is something I can use for this purpose, but I'm not entirely sure it's the right way to do it.

Is there some other, perhaps obvious way to do this? Or possibly, a better way to tackle this problem altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using meta fields in mapping should work, and is commonly used by several frameworks. But depends on the amount and structure of data/information needs to be stored and the way you want to work with that data.

If the amount of metadata needs to be larger or more complex, consider creating a meta index storing simple documents about the state of your indices. It will be also more efficient as index changes like mapping updates needs to be broadcasted in the cluster. Having such dedicated meta-data-index in place will ease a lot of other tasks like querying for all indices which are eligible for deletion etc. Using _meta you will not be able to implement something like versioning or history support. With the proposed meta index you can store one document per managed index or one per index and state change if you want some kind of history.

BTW: Elasticstack components create a lot of dot-prefixed-indicies like .kibana or .logstash; the reason is that these components needs to store some kind of state.

It's a more versatile solution from my point of view and worth to give it a try.

**EDIT summarizing the comments**:

As the metadata updates are infrequent and the related metadata-documents needs to be removed after the index has been deleted by ILM, the _meta stored approach should be the favorized one.

Comment: The data is just the state - so I guess it isn't much, but I also like your idea of a separate metadata index. However, how does it work with the ILM delete phase? If my index is going to be deleted in 3 days, how do I automatically delete the corresponding document in the metadata index? I can probably set the ttl on the metadata index to the same value so that the document expires after 3 days, but I believe ES has deprecated support for ttl.

Comment: Also, I don't need versioning/history, so that's that. But I'm a little concerned about the broadcasting of the mappings, considering meta sticks along with the properties, which means all of it has to be broadcasted even when I change just my metadata?

Comment: Yes, there is no ttl support for documents anymore. Your point is a valid one. As always every solution has up and downsides ;) As mentioned, if you have to store simple data and no further requirements, go for the _meta field as it will work as designed.

Comment: Exactly, it will be send with every mapping update. But this happens all the time in the cluster and if your changes are infrequent, don't mind it

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking at more than a couple of updates to the state, so I guess that's fine. I'm trying to see if there's some sort of a hook that i can attach to the delete phase in ILM, so that I can delete the corresponding document from the metadata index with your idea. Do you know if something like that's possible?

Comment: I don't know a suitable built insolution. Maybe the application layer creating the indicies can handle it? Maybe some kind of delete by query? But considering your comments I'd go with the _meta field at index level. The 'self disposposal' of the metadata together with the index is just elegant :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer based on our comments. Feel free to mark as accepted for future SO users. BTW: If you don't delete the meta docs in the meta index, you'll gain some kind of history you maybe can use for other purposes like billing or usage stats etc. Cheers!

Comment: I will do so in some time, just to see if I get anymore answers :)